# Set width of Progressbar as per value of Progress and based on Device Screen

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am using `ProgressBar` as a part of Custom `ListView`. Now, I want to display `ProgressBar`'s Width as per the value of `ProgressBar` and that is based on screen.
For i.e. If progress Value is 100 then it should show its width 100% of the device screen and like that for all 0-100 values.

**My Code is as below :**
**layout.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbTopicAccuracy"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAccuracy"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/pbTopicAccuracy"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/pbTopicAccuracy"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/pbTopicAccuracy"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code :**

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {

        if (view.getId() == R.id.pbTopicAccuracy) {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(data.toString());
            ((ProgressBar) view).setProgress(value);

            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.report);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(value, 30);
            ((ProgressBar) view).setLayoutParams(params);
        }
   }
});
```

It is working fine but It is not setting width as per it should be. If value is 100 then it sets width around like 4.5 part of the device screen.

How to prevent this problem and get proper width ?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the margin that you have defined that cause the problem?

```
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
```

If not, can you explain your problem with a picture?

Comment: No, it is different thing. because this RelativeLayout is parent of LinearLayout.

Comment: Can you do a screenshot of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by below code :

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
   int ratio = ((int) display.getWidth() /100) * value ;
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ratio, 30);
            ((ProgressBar) view).setLayoutParams(params);
```